# on_message stops all of my bot.commands from working

Tags: client, bots, discord.py

I have a flip command that returns either heads or tails and it was working fine until I added the `on_message` function. I did some research on SO and read the documentation and [here](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#why-does-on-message-make-my-commands-stop-working) it says to include `await bot.process_commands(message)` in the `on_message` function but that did not solve the issue and the flip command still doesn't work. If I remove the on_message function everything works as expected.

bot.py

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands 
import random

# from app bot user 
# click to reveal 
TOKEN = 'token_here'

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!')

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot ready')

@client.command()
async def flip():
    flip = random.choice(['heads', 'tails'])
    await client.say(flip)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith('N****'):
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Please do not use that word here.")

    client.process_commands(message)

@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Hi %s' % (member)))
    await client.send_message(member, "Hi %s, Welcome to Carson's Discord Server! This server is fairly NSFW at times; you've been warned! Enjoy your stay :)" % (member))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name='Bye %s' % (member)))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

When I run the script, everything else works normally with no errors. It's just the commands that don't work. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To whomever posted their answer; I tried that and it worked! I'm not sure why you deleted your answer but if you've like to repost it I'll choose it as best. Thank you.

Comment: you forgot to await, `process_commands()` is  a coroutine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `await` the last line in `on_message` as `process_commands` is a coroutine.

```
await client.process_commands(message)
```

If you send `!flip` in discord, you should be able to receive the appropriate response (`heads` or `tails`).

Comment: This fixed the issue I was having. Thanks.